# settingup juju in aws cloud, we are getting away from Maas

Tags: server, juju, cloud, aws

I got my server in aws and machines also in aws cloud. How can I setup juju where juju can use the server in aws for data and spin machines?  should i need to install juju in one of the machines as node or can i setup juju node in server so other users can also use it, how should i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here and review the process  https://docs.jujucharms.com/aws-cloud

I think this page will allow you to use JUJU with AWS.

Comment: Hi bogdan, thanks for the reply, I was facing this error while bootstraping controller in aws.
ERROR unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: dial tcp 172.18.1.143:17070: connect: connection refused.
whats this error, how to rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Juju [documentation for AWS](https://jaas.ai/docs/aws-cloud). There are 3 major steps:

- Create an account in the AWS console for Juju
- Add those AWS credentials via `juju add-credential` (You can also use `juju autoload-credentials`, which will grant Juju with the same access that the AWS command-line tools have)
- Bootstrap into AWS with `juju bootstrap`. Juju will install itself on any machines that it manages.

If you get stuck at any command, run `juju help <command>` or visit https://jaas.ai/docs.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply, I was facing this error while bootstrapping controller in aws.


*ERROR unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: dial tcp 172.18.1.143:17070: connect: connection refused*.
whats this error, how to rectify it.

Comment: It means that your machine can't contact the Juju controller. Do you have a restricted firewall environment?